# Переменная с JFrame1 в JFrame2 java

Tags: java

Скажите, как с одной формы `JFrame1` передать значение переменной `string` в другую форму `JFrame2`.

Comment: Передать параметром в конструктор или при вызове метода.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

По сути, вам нужно передать данные из одного класса в другой.

```
class JFrame1 extends JFrame {
    private String id = 1;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

class JFrame2 extends JFrame {
    private String id;

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame1 jFrame1 = new JFrame1();
    JFrame2 jFrame2 = new JFrame2();

    String id = jFrame1.getId(); // получаем данные из jFrame1
    jFrame2.setId(id); // передаём данные в jFrame2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделай это поле статичным приватным. Добавь к нему геттер. И смело обращайся к нему(геттеру) из JFrame2